# prove that $\Phi(x,y) $ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm wondering how to solve this. Suppose $\Phi(x,y) $ is defined on ${{\mathbb{R}}^{2}}$ such that for any 
$f\in C\left( \mathbb{R} \right),g\in C\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$,
$\Phi \left( f(x),g(x) \right)$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$.  prove that $\Phi(x,y) $ is measurable on ${{\mathbb{R}}^{2}}$.

I almost have no idea about it. At first I want to prove that for any $c$ ,
$\left\{ \left( x,y \right):\Phi \left( x,y \right)>c \right\}$
 is  measurable on $\left[ 0,1 \right]\times \left[ 0,1 \right]$.So I want to show $h(x)=m\left( \left\{ y\in \left[ 0,1 \right]:\Phi \left( x,y \right)>c \right\} \right)$ is measurable for $x\in \left[ 0,1 \right]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}{h(x)dx}=m\left( \left\{ \left( x,y \right):\Phi \left( x,y \right)>c \right\} \right)$. But it seems to be a harder problem. I think it might be another problem.

Thanks for any idea !

Comment: I'll try contrapositive, assume not, there is a Borel set where the inverse image is not measurable. Use that to construct $f,g\in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi(f,g)$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: Let $I=[0,1].$ The Hilbert curve $H:I\to I^2$ is onto and Holder $1/2.$ The hypotheses imply $\Phi\circ H$ is measurable. Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb R.$ Then $H^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(U))$ is measurable in $I.$ The last set is the same as $H^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(U)\cap I^2).$

Now prove yourself a little lemma: Suppose $E\subset I$ and $m_1(E) =0.$ If $f: I \to \mathbb R^2$ is Holder $1/2,$ then $m_2(f(I))=0.$

Corollary: By regularity, if $E\subset I$ is measurable, then $f(E)$ is measurable.

Back to our problem, where we know $E= H^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(U)\cap I^2)$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1].$ Hence $H(E) = \Phi^{-1}(U)\cap I^2$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ from the corollary. Now $I^2$ could have been any square. So taking the union over a grid of squares shows that the full $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is measurable. This shows $\Phi$ is measurable as desired.

I'm not sure we need all of this machinery, but it seems to work.